# angular formly - How to apply the custom css on dynamic label in angular formly?

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-formly

How to apply the custom css on dynamic label in angular formly?

For one of our formly modal, I am creating dynamic label as below.

```
   formlyConfig.templateOptions.wrapperLabel = 'Is '+ emailAddress + ' the best email?';

       emailAddress - populated by service.
```

would like to display this on UI as - Is **abc@abc.com** the best email?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will need to use the [Template Manipulators](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/advanced/template-manipulator) in Formly to add markup to your label.

Comment: Thanks! I am checking using manipulator and looks like I need to apply manipulator everywhere wherever needed. Though no performance impact as such but just need to make sure I am doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

or you can just write it as an HTML template in formly---much easier, and what I usually do when I need something like that.

```
{
   template: '<label>Is <strong>{{vm.email}}</strong> the best email?</label>'
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt! will it be 5 different template if I have to display bold at 5 different places? can this be generic?

Comment: Yes, you can add it to a global template page and just make it a type where you can call it from anywhere by setting the type in formly to whatever you name it.  See this for an example: http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/custom-templates